# SELECT same column AS different columns based on condition

Tags: sql, join, case

I am not very well versed on SQL, and I have found a workaround to do what I am looking for, but I am sure there is a more elegant way.

I have a SAS dataset (which I am accessing using SQL queries) that has a `month` column, the values of which look like `YYYYMM` with entries in 2016 and 2017 for a specific `memberid`, so `memberid` XYZ can have up to 24 rows for 201601 to 201712. There is also a `score` column that might or might not change for different year, but it never changes for different months in the same year.

Example:

```
memberid    month    score
XYZ         201601   1.0
XYZ         201602   1.0
XYZ         201703   1.5
```

So I would like a query that looks like:

```
SELECT <other table columns>,
       CASE WHEN el.month LIKE '2016%' THEN el.score AS score2016
            ELSE WHEN el.month LIKE '2017%' THEN el.score AS score2017 END
FROM <other table>
INNER JOIN elig AS el
ON <other table>.memberid = el.memberid
```

The query above (`CASE` statement is obviously syntactically funky, but the resulting table after the join should only have one record per member, and two new columns, one for `score2016` and one for `score2017`:

```
memberid    [...columns...]    score2016    score2017
XYZ               ...          1.0          1.5
```

Right now I am tackling this issue by creating separate tables for the 2016 and the 2017 entries of `elig`, followed by two JOINs, but I was wondering whether it can be done in one step with `CASE` more straightforwardly.

Comment: You could always use a `PIVOT`.  EDIT: Or what Gordon said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT <other table columns>,
       MAX(CASE WHEN el.month LIKE '2016%' THEN el.score END) AS score2016,
       MAX(CASE WHEN el.month LIKE '2017%' THEN el.score END) AS score2017 
FROM <other table> INNER JOIN 
     elig el
     ON <other table>.memberid = el.memberid
GROUP BY <other table columns>;
```